# Grammar rule be verb +ed

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

Please, can you explain me when we can use verb +ed like

> "you are allowed to..."?

I understand that the main meaning is that you are free to do something but I can't find the definition of this grammar rule.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you mentioned is a [passive-voice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/passive-voice) sentence.

You can make such passive-voice sentences with transitive verbs. To form the passive voice sentence, you need to know the [past-participle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/past-participle) of the intended verb. For many verbs the past participle is given by the pattern you mentioned- verb+ed.

- They allow you to stay here. (Active voice)
- You are allowed to stay here. (Passive voice)

Answer (score 1):

Many verbs can be followed by **object + infinitive**:

*I want you to listen.*

*I allow you to go.*

Sometimes, we can change these structures into passive voice:

I allow you to go. >> *You are allowed to go*.

Sometimes, **permission** is expressed by : **be allowed to** :

**You are allowed to go (giving permission)**.